# I've been encountering a lot of errors with \wrapfigure. Following is the code and the output. I don't understand what's the issue

Tags: wrapfigure

```
\label{my-label}
\begin{adjustbox}{width={\textwidth},totalheight={\textheight},keepaspectratio}%

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|p{12cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.5cm}}
    \\ \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Analysis} & \textbf{Score} & \textbf{Weighted Score} \\
     Technical Practicality & {\textbf{Efficiency} :  The EDDE space vehicle shows exceptional efficiency in terms of energy. The EDDE is a propellantless vehicle which relies on electrodynamic propulsion to generate thrust and practically “sail” through the Earth’s geomagnetic field while being powered by solar arrays. 
 & 4 & 0.8\\ \\ & \textbf{Effectiveness}: The EDDE claims to eliminate 99\% of the 2166 tons of debris in LEO in 7 years with 12 EDDE systems in orbit. However, the use of nets to grab the debris and drop it off at a lower orbit so as it de-orbits itself, caters to only mid to large size debris.  & 4 & 0.8} \\ \\  Recyclability \& Adaptability & \textbf{Adaptability} : The EDDE reaches its full potential as a “LEO taxi”. Its secondary applications include distribution of payloads launched with EDDE and to extend satellite lifetimes, there are concepts for service modules that can refuel satellites or even replace electronics modules. Therefore, EDDE shows immense amounts of adaptability.  & 5 & 0.5 \\ \\ & \textbf{Re-cyclability}: Once the net capture is complete, the EDDE taxis the debris to a lower orbit (a perigee of 200km and below) and cuts the net. At this altitude, the atmospheric drag causes a sharp decline in orbital velocity and the debris de-orbits, and due to this, an opportunity to recycle the debris materials is lost. & 0 & 0 \\ \\ Product Innovation & 
The EDDE shows remarkable innovation in its propulsion system, but not in its debris capture system. The use of nets to capture debris is a concept which restricts the effectiveness of the EDDE. & 3 & 0.6 \\ \\ Cost & EDDE estimates the cost for removal to be \$374 per kg and \$84M dollars annually to the customer.  Moreover, the EDDE provides secondary services to its customer, generating even more profits. 
 & 4 & 0.8 \\ \\ & \textbf{Total} & \textbf{20} & \textbf{3.6}\\

\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

%\caption{Competitive Analysis for EDDE}

\subsection{Panacea}
\subsubsection*{Introduction}

Panacea is a Space Debris Elimination system proposed by Sirona which is designed specifically for use in Low Earth Orbit (LEO). Panacea targets to remove cm size debris through an engulfing mechanism and consequently store the debris particles [1]][1]for recycling. Panacea is propelled through Hall Effect thrusters and is completely self-sufficient in terms of tracking and manoeuvring through multiple orbits.  
\\
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where's the wrapfigure? And what errors do you get? Furthermore it would be nice, if you could extend your code example to a compilable MWE.

Answer (score 1):

- your document example is not complete. missing are `\documentclass{...}` and document preamble. consequently your page layout is unknown.
- in your code snippet i don't see any `wrapfigure` ...
- but in the table you use curly braces enclosed two rows. this cause one error

i would redesign your table. at this i would:

- remove `adjustbox`
- use table environment, to which is possible prescribe the table width, like `tabular*`  or `tabularx`. in *mwe* below i use `tabularx`
- remove vertical lines
- in last two columns use shortens for column headers and add description of their meaning at bottom of table. this is reason to use `threeparttable` environment
- remove vertical lines
- add horizontal rules from `booktabs`
- for additional vertical space and column headers i use macros from  `maskecell`

[image]

(red lines indicate text margins on page)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx, threeparttable}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \newcommand{\sbf}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % <--
    \robustify\sbf                               % <--

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                             >{\raggedright}X
                                            p{10.5cm}
                                       *{2}{S[detect-weight, % <--
                                              mode=text,     % <--
                                              table-format=2.1]}
                             @{}}
    \toprule
\thead[b]{Parameter}
    &   \thead[b]{Analysis}
        &   {\thead[b]{S\tnote{a}}}
            &   {\thead[b]{WS\tnote{b}}}                    \\
    \midrule
Technical Practicality
    & \textbf{Efficiency} :  The EDDE space vehicle shows exceptional efficiency in terms of energy. The EDDE is a propellantless vehicle which relies on electrodynamic propulsion to generate thrust and practically “sail” through the Earth’s geomagnetic field while being powered by solar arrays.  & 4 & 0.8   \\
    & \textbf{Effectiveness}: The EDDE claims to eliminate 99\% of the 2166 tons of debris in LEO in 7 years with 12 EDDE systems in orbit. However, the use of nets to grab the debris and drop it off at a lower orbit so as it de-orbits itself, caters to only mid to large size debris.              & 4 & 0.8   \\
    \addlinespace
Recyclability \& Adaptability
    & \textbf{Adaptability} : The EDDE reaches its full potential as a “LEO taxi”. Its secondary applications include distribution of payloads launched with EDDE and to extend satellite lifetimes, there are concepts for service modules that can refuel satellites or even replace electronics modules. Therefore, EDDE shows immense amounts of adaptability.                            & 5 & 0.5   \\
    \addlinespace
    & \textbf{Re-cyclability}: Once the net capture is complete, the EDDE taxis the debris to a lower orbit (a perigee of 200km and below) and cuts the net. At this altitude, the atmospheric drag causes a sharp decline in orbital velocity and the debris de-orbits, and due to this, an opportunity to recycle the debris materials is lost.                                       & 0 & 0     \\
    \addlinespace
Product Innovation
    & The EDDE shows remarkable innovation in its propulsion system, but not in its debris capture system. The use of nets to capture debris is a concept which restricts the effectiveness of the EDDE.              & 3 & 0.6   \\
    \addlinespace
Cost
    & EDDE estimates the cost for removal to be \$374 per kg and \$84M dollars annually to the customer.  Moreover, the EDDE provides secondary services to its customer, generating even more profits.               & 4 & 0.8   \\
    \midrule
    & \textbf{Total}                            & \sbf 20   & \sbf 3.6  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
\item[a]    S: Score
\item[b]    WS: Weighted Score
\end{tablenotes}
\caption{Competitive Analysis for EDDE}
    \end{threeparttable}

\subsection{Panacea}
\subsubsection*{Introduction}
Panacea is a Space Debris Elimination system proposed by Sirona which is designed specifically for use in Low Earth Orbit (LEO). Panacea targets to remove cm size debris through an engulfing mechanism and consequently store the debris particles [1]][1] for recycling. Panacea is propelled through Hall Effect thrusters and is completely self-sufficient in terms of tracking and maneuvering through multiple orbits.
\end{document}
```